# No Privileges error in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In phpMyAdmin in my server, When trying to view the table `USER_STATISTICS` in `information_schema` Database, This error comes in. Is it normal or need something to be done ?

[image]

Comment: go to privilege tab on top links and edit the privileges.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala I can't see such a tab :(

Comment: Have you login with your `root` user `privileges`?

Comment: @TharinduLucky check out my answer below.

Comment: This is how the USER_PREVILEGES table look like https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4m50qjw51qvzaf/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: @TharinduLucky just substitute the user name and password in the answer below and run the query in `phpmyadmin` it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, just execute this query as root user:

```
 GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: Thanks but, I want to know why this is happening. This is my login user and I don't have full access... Why ?

Comment: Post the error you get after running the above query.

Comment: This is the error I get after the execution of ur code https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4m50qjw51qvzaf/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: @TharinduLucky you are not logged in using root privileges. Please get the root id and pwd from database administrator.

Comment: I'm the owner of this hosting account and where to get or find that credentials ?